# Properties file causes exception on empty Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot project and it's empty, no other classes. I want to connect to my MySQL database so my properties file looks like this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = "PASSWORD"
```

When I run the project the following exceptions are appearing. Keep in mind, that the empty Spring Boot project runs without exceptions when I don't add any MySQL related lines on properties file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at test.com.clubapi.ClubApiApplication.main(ClubApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:64) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.createJpaVendorAdapter(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:103) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d92fc69.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d92fc69$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d46b013f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d92fc69.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>club-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>club-api</name>
    <description>Spring Boot project for CLUB application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Main Class

```
package test.com.clubapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ClubApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClubApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Edit: I even downloaded the tutorial project from spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ and the same exceptions are happening.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException`

Comment: How are you running the program? Maven?

Comment: @Thihara as a Spring Boot App from STS

Comment: Can you paste `Controller` class and your `Repository` interface?

Comment: @harshavmb I don't have them yet. It's an empty project, I haven't done anything else to it except adding these lines on properties file. I had a project with `Controller` and `Repository` and this is when I faced these exceptions , so I created an empty project to find the problem and the problem is on properties file and especially on MySQL related lines

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of your project structure? Not sure how you are starting the app.

Comment: @harshavmb Here it is [project structure](http://imgur.com/yoqxx8G) . Also , I run it as a Spring Boot App and java application (both have the same result)

Comment: Try `Run as -> Maven clean` and then run it as a Spring boot app.

Comment: @Abdullah Khan same result.

Comment: okay. this appears to be because of your pom. Have tried in my local and it worked for me. https://pastebin.com/FbUT9x3x is my pom. Can you remove  `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>` from your pom and try?

Comment: prune the repository. Do a `dependency:purge-local-repository` this will remove all dependencies and re download. You probably have a borked hibernate jar.

Comment: Also `spring.datasource.password` in `application.properties` has password in double quotes "PASSWORD". All the properties in `application.properties` are strings, no need to explicitly add ""

Comment: @M.Deinum, to connect to MySQL, no need to use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` API, I think that has introduced this hibernate conflict. 
I tried without it and able to connect to mysql

Comment: Once the app starts up, run `show processlist;` in mysql client and check whether your root has connected to `mydb` database

Comment: @harshavmb I removed the JPA dependency but it is need because it couldn't recognise libraries like `javax.persistence.Entity;` etc. Also this isn't my password, I changed it to post  my question here.

Comment: okay, if you don't have repositories and entity classes, why are you worried about recognizing Entity libraries? If that is the case, you should have repositories as well. To test controllers.

Comment: Am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve with your project

Comment: @harshavmb read the exception. There is no problem in connecting to MySQL there is a problem with Hibernate and its dependencies. There isn't a conflict (the starters help with preventing those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it on STS and IntelliJ the problem clearly seemed to be about Maven. So I deleted the folder `~/.m2/repository` and I built the project again and no more exceptions.